# While loop and if statement trouble

Tags: input, while-loop, try-catch

When I put in the account number in the terminal window I get this error

The data I put into it is correct, I put a string such as"ste251" into accountand an int such as 500 into balance.

Also when I try to stop the loop when it throws the mismatch exeption I get:

> ```
> Java.util.inputMismatchException: null (in Java.util.scanner)
>
> java.util.InputMismatchException
> at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
> at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
> at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
> at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
> at WriteAccountBalances.writeToFile(WriteAccountBalances.java:58)
> ```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you already asked this question earlier...

Comment: really need the help man

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error when calling one of these nextInt() or next() methods, because input values are not matching the pattern of next*() methods. Try to debug your code by putting break-points, you will find easily.

> it should continue to ask for account numbers and balances until the
>   user enters a capital X

Write something like this:

```
   while(true){
    //....
    //...
       System.out.print("Enter account number or X for exit: ");
        String option= myScanner.nextLine();
        if("X".equals(option)){
          break;
        }
        //....
       //...
    }
```

PS:
never use this kind of `try/catch`:

```
  try {
        output.println(account + " " + balance);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        System.out.println("PrintWriter is not assigned");
    }
```

instead check it with if statements:

```
if(output!=null){
        output.println(account + " " + balance);
    }else{
        System.out.println("PrintWriter is not assigned");
    }
```

Comment: Really sorry but i'm awul at this, is that the completed code or do i fit that around my existing code, i don't quite see what you're doing there?

Comment: This is something more general, you can easily fit your condition for more try googling :)

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs for InputMismatchException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html):

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.

That pretty much says all that needs to be said. Check for unexpected input.

Answer (score 0):

Since your entire code seems to be unavailable, it would be irksome for a third party like me to come in and reconstruct the whole example. Rather, as this is a trivial case, I'll provide you with a similar, complete and easy-to-understand example which I already happen to have. This code takes input in a manner similar to what you need; you should be able to modify it according to your specific requirements.

```
//Filename: "Hotel.java"
import java.util.*;

class Customer
{
    private String name;
    private int room;

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setRoom(int room)
    {
        this.room=room;
    }

    public int getRoom()
    {
        return this.room;
    }
}

class Hotel
{
    public static void initialize(Customer RoomList[])
    {
        for(int i=0; i<RoomList.length; i++)
        {
            RoomList[i]=new Customer();
            RoomList[i].setName("EMPTY");
            RoomList[i].setRoom(i+1);
        }
    }

    public static void viewList(Customer RoomList[])
    {
        for(int i=0; i<RoomList.length; i++)
        {
            if(RoomList[i].getName()=="EMPTY")
                System.out.println("Room number "+RoomList[i].getRoom()+" is vacant.");
            else
                System.out.println("Room number "+RoomList[i].getRoom()+" is ocupied by "+RoomList[i].getName()+".");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static boolean addCustomer(Customer RoomList[], String name)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<RoomList.length; i++)
            if(RoomList[i].getName().equals("EMPTY"))
            {
                RoomList[i].setName(name);
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }

    public static void showEmptyRooms(Customer RoomList[])
    {
        System.out.println("Available rooms are:");
        for(int i=0; i<RoomList.length; i++)
            if(RoomList[i].getName()=="EMPTY")
                System.out.println(RoomList[i].getRoom());
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static boolean deleteCustomer(Customer RoomList[], String name)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<RoomList.length; i++)
            if(RoomList[i].getName().equals(name))
            {
                RoomList[i].setName("EMPTY");
                System.out.println("Deletion successful.\n");
                return true;
            }
        return false;
    }

    public static int getIndex(Customer RoomList[], String name)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<RoomList.length; i++)
            if(RoomList[i].getName().equals(name))
                return i;
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Customer[] RoomList = new Customer[12];
        String name;
        initialize(RoomList);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int option=0;

        do
        {
            System.out.println("        Hotel Booking Options");
            System.out.println("=====================================");
            System.out.println("1: To View all rooms");
            System.out.println("2: To Add customer to a room");
            System.out.println("3: To Display empty rooms");
            System.out.println("4: To Delete customer from a room");
            System.out.println("5: Find room from customer name");
            System.out.println("0: Exit");

            System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
            option = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println();

            switch(option)
            {
                case 1:
                {
                    viewList(RoomList);
                    break;
                }
                case 2:
                {
                    System.out.print("Customer's name: ");
                    name=input.next();
                    System.out.println();
                    if(!addCustomer(RoomList, name))
                        System.out.println("No rooms available!");
                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                {
                    showEmptyRooms(RoomList);
                    break;
                }
                case 4:
                {
                    System.out.print("Customer's name: ");
                    name=input.next();
                    System.out.println();
                    deleteCustomer(RoomList, name);
                    break;
                }
                case 5:
                {
                    System.out.print("Customer's name: ");
                    name=input.next();
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Customer's room: "+RoomList[getIndex(RoomList, name)].getRoom()+"\n");
                    break;
                }
                case 0:
                {
                    System.out.println("\nThank you!\n");
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid option!\n");
                    break;
                }
            }


        }while(option!=0);
    }
}
```

### EDIT

I tried your code; I'm not sure what the issue is because this seems to be working fine for me:

```
//Filename: "myPrg.java"
import java.util.*;

class myPrg {
    static Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int count = 0;

    public static void writeToFile(String account, int balance) {
        while (!account.equals("X")) {
            System.out.print("Enter account balance: ");
            balance = myScanner.nextInt();
            try {
                System.out.println(account + " " + balance);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                System.out.println("PrintWriter is not assigned");
            }
            count++;
            System.out.print("Enter account number: ");
            account = myScanner.next();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter account number: ");
        String account = myScanner.next();
        writeToFile(account, 0);
        System.out.println("Code terminated successfully!");
    }
}
```

This gave me the following in the terminal:

```
Enter account number: qwerty
Enter account balance: 123
qwerty 123
Enter account number: asdfgh
Enter account balance: 456
asdfgh 456
Enter account number: X
Code terminated successfully!
```

Comment: THANK YOU, obviosly i'm a total novice

Comment: @user2292357: I have edited my answer. Your code seems to be working fine; you can check the slightly edited version I've attached below.